# Attempted to call an undefined method named "search" of class "FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository"

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I want to use search method from elastica repository but i got error 
`Attempted to call an undefined method named "search" of class "FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository".`
I use symfony 4 with fos elastica bundle, latest version. In repo i working find method but it don't return any results.
I want do search-as-you-type-autocomplete like here https://www.codevate.com/blog/14-implementing-search-as-you-type-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-symfony

Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/search")
     */
    public function searchElastic(RepositoryManagerInterface $finder, Request $request){
        $searchTerm = $request->query->get('s');
        $searchTerm = htmlentities($searchTerm, ENT_QUOTES);

//        $finder = $finder->getRepository(\App\Entity\User::class)->find($searchTerm);
//        return new response(var_dump($finder[0]->getUsername()));

        $completion = new Suggest\Completion('suggest', 'name_suggest');
        $completion->setText($searchTerm);
        $completion->setFuzzy(array('fuzziness' => 2));
        /** var array of App\Entity\User */
        $resultSet = $finder->getRepository(\App\Entity\User::class)->search((Query::create($completion)));
        var_dump($resultSet);
        $suggestions = array();
        foreach ($resultSet->getSuggests() as $suggests) {
            foreach ($suggests as $suggest) {
                foreach ($suggest['options'] as $option) {
                    $suggestions[] = array(
                        'id' => $option['_source']['id'],
                        'username' => $option['_source']['username']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'suggestions' => $suggestions,
        ));
    }
```

Config:

```
# Read the documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/setup.md
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
#    indexes:
#        app: ~
    indexes:
        app:
            client: default
#FOR AUTOCOMPLETE
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            name_analyzer:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: standard
                                filter: [standard, lowercase, asciifolding, elision]
#END FOR AUTOCOMPLETE
            types:
                user:
                    properties:
#                        username: ~
#                        username:
                        name_suggest:
                          #                    MAPPINGS ADDED FOR AUTOCOMPLETE
                            type: completion
                            analyzer: name_analyzer
                            search_analyzer: name_analyzer
#                            payloads: true
                        id:
                            type: keyword
                        username:
                            type: keyword

#MAPPINGS ADDED FOR AUTOCOMPLETE
                    persistence:
                        # the driver can be orm, mongodb, phpcr or propel
                        # listener and finder are not supported by
                        # propel and should be removed
                        driver: orm
                        model: App\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

User entity

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Elastica\Search;

/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Search(repositoryClass="AppBundle\SearchRepository\PropositionRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

Please help, i'm beginner in elastica.

**UPADTE:**

Now i get this error.

`Cannot autowire argument $finder of "App\Controller\DevController::searchElastic2()": it references class "FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\RepositoryManager" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "FOS\ElasticaBundle\Manager\RepositoryManagerInterface" instead.`

**UPDATE:**

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\UserRepository::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface, instance of FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\symfonysite\vendor\friendsofsymfony\elastica-bundle\src\Manager\RepositoryManager.php on line 101
```

**UPDATE:**

UserRepository.php [a link](https://pastebin.com/3BvB1RP0)

User.php entity [a link](https://pastebin.com/nRPFu8Jj)

Controller [a link](https://pastebin.com/TfstCzrX)

**Update: **

I don't get it. Tutorial in link reqire search function which is not in my version, and find function which work for me find only one resuly. Here's simple code which work for me, but find one result.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/search")
     */
    public function searchElastic(RepositoryManagerInterface $finder, Request $request){
        $searchTerm = $request->query->get('s');
        $searchTerm = htmlentities($searchTerm, ENT_QUOTES);

        $finder = $finder->getRepository(\App\Entity\User::class)->find($searchTerm);

        return new response(var_dump($finder[0]->getUsername())); //i tried changing index to 1 but always it return undefined offset
```

Comment: Can you try to inject `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Doctrine\RepositoryManager` instead of your `RepositoryManagerInterface` ?

Comment: `Repository` class doesn't have `search()` method. The tutorial you mentioned calles `search()` on `Elastica\Index` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Search annotation support has been removed the a look to this merged [PR](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/pull/1119/files) , as the repository should be no more accessed through the Bundle:Entity notation, but requesting index/type.

To use the custom repository specify it in the mapping for your user just decalre it under your `fos_elastica`:

```
fos_elastica:
    ...
    indexes:
        app:
            client: default
            types:
                user:
                    properties:
                        # your properties
                    persistence:
                        ...
                        repository: App\Repository\UserRepository
```

Then the custom queries will be available when using the repository returned from the manager:

```
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository;

class UserRepository extends Repository
{
  ...
  function search(RepositoryManagerInterface $finder, Request $request)
    {
    /** var FOS\ElasticaBundle\Manager\RepositoryManagerInterface */
    $repositoryManager = $finder;
    /** var FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository */
    $repository = $repositoryManager->getRepository(AppEntityUser::class);

    /** var array of Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User */
    $users = $repository->search('bob');
....
```

Comment: @user10567054 try too look to my update. I missed something. You need touse `RepositoryManagerInterface ` for autowring to access to your repository.

Comment: your `UserRepository ` should extends `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository` take a look to my code...could you show me your `UserRepository` class

Comment: I added but it don't change any thing. Links in update.

Comment: Could you show me this class `AppBundle\SearchRepository\PropositionRepository` and clear your cache pleaz

Comment: I don't have proposition repository. I will clear cache. look at update

Comment: `AppBundle\SearchRepository\PropositionRepository` is not what i have, i copy paste this, after change it to `@Search(repositoryClass="AppBundle\SearchRepository\UserRepository")` no change. Should i write here `App/Repository/UserRepository` ?

Comment: hmmm what repo contain `search()` function ?

Comment: I thought it is elastica function not my repo function. I wanted do it like in https://www.codevate.com/blog/14-implementing-search-as-you-type-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-symfony but i have latest version which is not the same.

Comment: Ohhhh no way ...then you you use a repository ?

Comment: I think you dont need to use repository, and you miss explain your problem. You can just inject `PaginatedFinderInterface ` and then call to search() method

Comment: error from above code is `Cannot autowire argument $finder of "App\Controller\DevController::searchElastic2()": it references interface "FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\PaginatedFinderInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "fos_elastica.finder.app.user" service.`

Comment: Yeah you soud define the correct arguments under your DevController...cant help you so mush sorry. you should back to fos doc and take a look how you define arguments service

Comment: Where i can find the docs? I really want to do it. Why it isn't working while i'm making it exactly like in link?

Comment: Ok i found the doc https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/

Comment: Why there are no search method?! There is only find, which worked for me. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/usage.md

Comment: find return ydrateted object, search return json format and to use search i think you should inject `Elastica\Type`